# Converting publisher files for use on Mac

Tags: mac

I have Microsoft publisher files on a windows computer.  I recently purchased a macbook air, and would like to move these files to my new computer.  How do I do that?

Comment: I assume you don't want to simply copy over the Publisher files (since there is no Microsoft Publisher for Mac). What file type do you want to convert the files to: Word doc, PDF, JPG, etc.?

Comment: Good Luck! As a designer, I've been looking for a program that would open a Publisher file on a Mac for about 12 years. I hope someone has found one.

Answer (score 6):

LibreOffice 4.0 and later can open publisher files.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned there is no Mac application that can work with Publisher files.
(EDIT: As Tom pointed out [LibreOffice 4.0 and above](http://www.libreoffice.org), released in February 2013, can now open and work with Publisher files)

What I've recommended for people at our office who have made the switch to Mac is to either export to a different format (Word, PDF, etc) from Publisher on their PC beforehand.

Alternately you can use online services to convert the Publisher file into a PDF, Word doc, etc.  I know there are several but the only I've actually used is the [service from Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/convert/pub-to-pdf/).

Hope that helps!

Comment: "No application" is incorrect, as Tom has pointed out. LibreOffice 4.0 and above has Publisher file support.

Comment: @aglasser - Gotcha.  He responded after me.  I haven't had any requests for Publisher at work over the past year so I hadn't been aware that LibreOffice now had the functionality.  Good to know!

Comment: I didn't even check the timestamps! Sorry about that. I was just clarifying.